# Filter DataFrame by selecting the first row with not-NaN in the given column (or any one row if doesn't exist)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df with (at least) two columns: `id`, `value` and possibly more. `id`'s are not unique. I need to filter the dataframe so that only one row per id remains. The row I want to select is the row where value is not `NaN`. It is guaranteed that there is at most one such row. For those id's with all `NaN`'s in the value column I don't care which row is selected. What is the best way to achieve this?

Example: if the dataframe is

```
id  other   value
0   0   3.14
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
1   3   NaN
```

the result may be either

```
id  other   value
0   0   3.14
1   2   NaN
```

or

```
id  other   value
0   0   3.14
1   3   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `sort_values`, there is a parameter `na_position` which defaults to 'last' meaning that it will push all NaN for that column to the bottom.  Therefore, you can use the following to get a single records for each 'id'.

```
df.sort_values(by='value').groupby('id').head(1)
```

Output:

```
   id  other  value
0   0      0   3.14
2   1      2    NaN
```

## Timing:

**Abdou Solution:**

f = lambda x: x.head(1) if x.value.isnull().all() else x[~x.value.isnull()].head(1)

df.groupby('id').apply(f)

*100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop*

**This solution**

df.sort_values(by='value').groupby('id').head(1)

*1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop*

Comment: I need to preserve the original sorting order. Otherwise this would have probably been a better solution.

Comment: I take that back. Even with re-sorting this solution is faster than the other one by a huge margin. In my case much more so than Scott's little test indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is called `dff`, the following should do:

```
f = lambda x: x.head(1) if x.value.isnull().all() else x[~x.value.isnull()].head(1)

dff.groupby('id').apply(f)
```

Output:

```
#       id  other  value
# id                    
# 0  0   0      0   3.14
# 1  2   1      2    NaN
```

It groups the dataframe by the `id` column first. If all elements in the `value` column are `null`, it takes the first row. Otherwise, it filters out `null` values and take the first row of the output.

I hope this helps.